# Excel Match to Table Header from three criteria

Tags: excel, function

I am trying pull a rank value (UN, NI, AE, HE, EX) from table headers, when individual score is compared to the table of goals. The Match criteria must include level and quarter, as the goals increase each quarter and goal ranges are different per individual's level.

I have tried xlookup, but I cant get it to work has #value! error

```
=XLOOKUP(B2&E2&D3,Goals[[ Level]]&Goals[Quarter]&Goals[[UN]:[EX]],Goals[[#Headers],[UN]:[EX]])
```

I have tried index match combination, but could not figure out a proper formula for the 3 criteria. I did not get it to work, and I did not get it to include a 3rd match criteria either.

```
=INDEX(Goals[[#Headers],[UN]:[EX]],,MATCH(D3,INDEX(B8:F11,MATCH(B2,A8:A11,0),,),-1),)
```

The goal is to fill in cell B4 with the equivalent ranking value which equates to the the headers in cells B7:F7. If person's score is equal to or greater than a level and quarter goal then they should get a ranking matching that column's header as long as it is not greater than the next column's goal.

[image]

Comment: I think you should post a example of expected output.

Comment: In this example the expected output would be in B4 value of NI as the current score of 44.74% is above the Q1 level 3 NI goal but below the Q1 Level 3 AE goal.

Answer (score 2):

You need two `XLOOKUP` calls, one to pick the row and then one to match the column.  Try this.

```
=XLOOKUP(D3,XLOOKUP(B2&E2,Goals[Level]&Goals[Quarter],Goals[[UN]:[EX]]),Goals[[#Headers],[UN]:[EX]],"",-1)
```